# Long Term Investing in leveraged ETFs such as TQQQ

Tags: united-states, stocks, leveraged-etf

I am currently investing in TQQQ. My plan is to keep it for the long term. I have read that long term investing in leveraged ETFs is bad. Is that true? If it is I do not understand why since the stock market long term trend is up.

Note: I understand that dividends from TQQQ are not qualified and therefore I am doing it in my Roth IRA.

Comment: Please cite an example of such writing.  Their "why" could be a point of agreement or disagreement.

Comment: Take this example: QQQ is down 9% from its high in Nov 2021, while TQQQ is down  57% over the same time. The problem is that large downward movements can be catastrophic for a leveraged fund.

Comment: It's basically a bet, and just as with roulette - statistically you have a very high chance to eventually win if betting indefinitely. But can you afford all the losses until then?